Filter Measure of dimensional table with another dimensional table
My model looks like this:

My fact table contains insurance claims and my dimension tables, for example, customer (D_Person), vehicle (D_Vehicle), contract (D_Coverage) data (and some more).
Suppose I want to calculate the total premia. The column premium is in the dimension table D_Coverage. To do this I define the measure: "Premia_sum = SUM(D_COVERAGE[premium])"
This works for the overall sum but let's assume I want to see only the premium a certain agent (in D_AGENT) acquired. The filter wont work because premium is part of another dimension table and not the fact table. D_COVERAGE is a dimension table because I have one row per contract with one individual premium, whereas I could have multiple claims per contract (F_CLAIM).
I tried to change the directions of the filters to bi-directional and it seemed to work but I want to avoid this if possible and stick to a classical star/snowflake schema because as far as I know using bi-directional relationships is not recommended. How can I do this? Treat the contract table D_COVERAGE as a fact table even though it is only one row per contract?
Thanks.
